# Mapping object keys in react and returning child properties

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a report that maps the number of objects. In my example there is 3 object arrays. I want to get a value of one of the properties in each object when it maps.

Here is my snippet React code that returns the reports:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        { Object.keys(result).map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="report">
                    <h3>{result[item].name}</h3>
            </div>
    ))}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

It maps `const result` that outputs like:

```
result = {GK: Array(1), FB: Array(2), FW: Array(1)}
```

There are 3 reports above - GK, FB and FW

I now want to go into each report and get a value. Lets look at FB:

```
FB: [ 0:{Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "FB" }
      1:{Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "FB" }
    ]
```

I want to make sure that when I retrieve the report the `name` property also maps and any other property I want to grab.

```
<h3>{result[item].name}</h3>
```

I thought the above would retrieve name. So the result I get is 3 blank reports.

Comment: It seems like result[item] should be an array correct? So you would need to map over that array as well. result[item][0].name should return the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Again `map` through the inner elements present in the `result[item]`.

```
   return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { Object.keys(result).map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="report">
                       {result[item].map((media,ind) =>
                         <div key={ind}>{media.name}</div>
                      )}
                </div>
        ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code : Here is the link to the code on:  https://codesandbox.io/s/pj1lv7y4xq

```
const arrayvals = [
   { Number: 1, newNumber: "1", name: "FB" },
    { Number: 3, newNumber: "2", name: "FB" },
     { Number: 7, newNumber: "5", name: "GK" },
      { Number: 8, newNumber: "4", name: "FW" }
]



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Mapping object keys in react and returning child properties
</h1>
    {Object.entries(arrayvals).map((arr)=>{

        return <div>Number is : {arr[1].Number}  || NewNumber is : {arr[1].newNumber} ||  and Value is : {arr[1].name}</div>
    })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map again on the `result` using the `key` obtained as

```
   <React.Fragment>
        {Object.keys(result).map((key, i) => (result[key].map((media, ind) =>
              <div key={ind}>
               <h3>{media.name}</h3>
             </div>
            )
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
```